# magento rewrite not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, configuration, magento

I created a module that used a custom widget/grid/column for my admin grid to display a thumbnail image and everything worked.  Now I need to create another module in the same project that does the same thing, but the image column will not work.  It appears like its not even loading my new class, since it won't execute any stmt I put into the file.   I know its properly loading data, b/c if I change the type to text, then the correct info from the DB is populated into the field.  But when I change to my new 'image' type the cell is empty. does anyone know why it wouldn't be working?

**ABT/Background/etc/config.xml** << doesn't work

```
<global>
    ....
    <blocks>
        <background>
            <class>ABT_Background_Block</class>
        </background>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <widget_grid_column>ABT_Background_Block_Widget_Grid_Column</widget_grid_column>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
    ....
</global>
```

the module I copied to get me up and running has the exact same config setup, but yet it works fine
**ABT/Feature/etc/config.xml**  << this works correctly

```
<global>
    ....
    <blocks>
        <feature>
            <class>ABT_Feature_Block</class>
        </feature>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <widget_grid_column>ABT_Feature_Block_Widget_Grid_Column</widget_grid_column>   
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
    ....
</global>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happening with Magento when you rewrite a class.

When Magento instantiates a Block class, it uses code something like the following

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_grid_column')
```

The `createBlock` method is a factory.  Magento uses the identifier

```
adminhtml/widget_grid_column
```

to lookup which class should be instantiated. By default, that's

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column
```

When you create your rewrite, you're telling Magento

> Hey. instead of using 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column' for a 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column', you should use 'ABT_Background_Block_Widget_Grid_Column'

This means that, for any given system, a class may only be rewritten **once**.  In the code you're showing above, you're trying to rewrite the class twice.  Only one of your rewrites will win.

The quick approach I'd take is to keep **all** your customizations in a single override class.

More generally, I try to avoid using rewrites if at all possible.  They're a powerful system, but should be using sparingly.  I haven't done much grid customizing, but the general approach I'd try to take would be to change the adminhtml layout to instantiate a new grid class from my custom module that **extends** an existing grid class, which in turn may use custom column classes.

More work up front, but once you've figured it out you can use the technique over and over again, and not worry abou conflicts from a rewrite.

Comment: This sounds like a better approach than what I'm doing. Like I said above, this is my first project w/ magento so I'm new to all of this.  You wouldn't happen to know of any resources that could help me limp along doing what you describe do you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. Most of the articles written online about Magento are recipe based. "Do this to make that happen", and most are in love with the rewrite method.  If you need to get your job done ASAP, I'd continue with the approach you had, but just add additional logic into your single override class methods.  I've written a bunch of in depth articles (plug: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) that can help you understand the system enough to take the approach I've recommended yourself, but there's a learning curve that needs to be surmounted.

Comment: Oh well, I should be able to stumble along enough to get this going.  thanks for your insight and website, I'll definitely give it a look over!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to have got your setup correctly.

Anyway, it looks like you have two override rules on the same class `Widget_Grid_Column`. The last module loaded is the `ABT_Feature` so the rule of that block overwrite the rule of the `ABT_Background` module.

You have two solutions:

1. merge the Feature and Background module in a single one
2. make the Feature block depending on the Background one and update the rewrite rule so that the `ABT_Feature_Block_Widget_Grid_Column` class will extend the `ABT_Background_Block_Widget_Grid_Column`.

Comment: You are probably right - chances are I don't have this setup correctly.  This is my first time working w/ Magento and I simply followed this guide to get my new type working  http://www.krishnasunuwar.com.np/2009/07/ecommerce-software-magento-showing-image-in-grid/